# Using 'NOT' operator in Sphinx Search?

Tags: sphinx

I have a index 'order' with field id, date, and status. I need to get all order not having status **CLOSED**.

My sphinx Query is :

```
SELECT id, status FROM order 
WHERE MATCH('@status "!CLOSED"') AND id < 21;


+------+-------------+
| id   | status      | 
+------+-------------+
|   10 | CLOSED      |
|    1 | CLOSED      |
|    4 | CLOSED      |
|    5 | CLOSED      |
|    7 | CLOSED      |
|    9 | CLOSED      |
|   14 | CLOSED      |
|   18 | CLOSED      |
|   19 | CLOSED      |
+------+-------------+
9 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

Where I went wrong? If I want to do NOT in multiple field how to do that?
Can you please rewrite this SphinxQL for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've put the term in phrase operators, so its looking for the phrase `!CLOSED` - but as I doubt that you have ! in your `charset_table` its ignored, so becomes just a search for CLOSED.

```
... WHERE MATCH('@status !CLOSED')
```

would in theory work. But sphinx can't execute a query with just 'NOT' terms. 
Sphinx has an inverted index, listing which words are in which documents. It doesnt have a list of all documents that it can then 'remove' specific ones.

... so you need a list of all documents. Easiest is to add a fake keyword to all documents, eg modify your source definition (in sphinx.conf) to add a fake field something like...

```
sql_query = SELECT id,...,'_all' as fake FROM sqltable ...
```

Then can using it in your sphinx queries....

```
... WHERE MATCH('_all @status -CLOSED')
```

Comment: if i do select id, status, '_all' as fake  from order WHERE MATCH('_all @status -CLOSED'). gives me an error **sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected AS, expecting '=' near 'as fake ***

Comment: You need to modify the index to have the fake field, the sql_query is used to build the index. Nothing to do with SphinxQL.